# run AR codes in eclipse emulator

Tags: android-emulator, augmented-reality

Im new in augmented reality.I get sample codes and change them to learn codes. but i dont know how to run these codes in eclipse emulator and see the result. I run the code in eclipse and copy the apk file in my phone ,then see the result in my phone. Is there any way to see the result of change in eclipse emulator? please help me.

Comment: What AR SDK/framework are you using?

Comment: I use vuforia sdk in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There are many threads on the Vuforia developer forum, such as [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/qcar-sdk-android-emulator), that mention the SDK does not support the Android emulator. This is has been my experience with every AR SDK I have worked with... you have to test on a real device.

Comment: Can i use webcam to get picture in emulator?

Comment: It's still probably not going to work. I tried that once (with Vuforia if memory serves) and although the Webcam could mimic a camera it was not good enough for AR tracking, etc. You need a real phone.

Comment: Can you suggest another IDE for creating a AR application on android that solve my problem? like IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I've only used Eclipse/Android for AR development and every technology I have tried always came with the precondition that you can't test via the Emulator... you might look into non-smartphone based libraries like perhaps ARToolkit or OpenCV if you really cannot develop with a smarthphone or tablet.